# How do I find the properties of this function?

Tags: functions

I am a high school student of Mathematics. I have been working on this piece-wise function, trying to understand its properties:-
[image: Piece-wise function]

[**N** is the set of all natural numbers, **W** is the set of all whole numbers. The *mod* function gives the remainder when *n* is divided by 2]

I thought of finding a single function that has the same value as that of this piece-wise function in its domain, and trying to evaluate the properties of the new function. Firstly, is that a good idea? Or, is there another way out?

I want to find properties of the function so that I can subject it to further algebraic treatment. Also, please guide me to systematically analyze the function so that I can derive fruitful results using the same. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is  **W** ?

Comment: In India, W is the set of non-negative integers, and N is W-{0}. High school textbooks are ****.

Comment: @gammatester I have edited and made the declaration of the sets in my question itself...